# Data URI Image crashes on old computer

Tags: image, fckeditor, data-uri, genexus

I'm using an genexus application, and his HTML editor is a little... old. 
Since he doesn't give me the option to browse a image from my computer, I converted a image to Data URI and placed in there.
[image: FCK Editor]

Works just fine!
At least in my computer.

In my customer's computer, when I try to do the same thing, crashes his browser.
We are both using Chrome.

Any ideas about what to do with this? Any workaround? I'm hoping to not have to mess with my back-end application just for this because reasons. Any idea is appreciated.

Comment: Could it be related to where the web app is running? Maybe if it's running on your machine it allows the data URIs?

Comment: I guess it's related to the browser version, are you using the same version?  Anyway it's browser related, shouldn't crash

Comment: Yeah, we are using the same version. and yep, found out it is indeed browser related. Tried in Firefox and worked. Not sure what a hell happened with Chrome tho.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid using a data URI. This article explains how to setup `CKEditor` with `GeneXus` to be able to browse for a local image and have it uploaded (check the downloadable sample at the end of the article):

[HowTo: Drag & Drop an Image in FCK Editor Control](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?31817,HowTo%3A%20Drag%20%26%20Drop%20an%20Image%20in%20FCK%20Editor%20Control)

As for the browser crash, take a look at this bug report on CKEditor's site: [Image upload in data-uri base64 doesn't work with large files](https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/10391). It seems it's an old problem and they don't have a solution for it.

Comment: Oh thanks! Sums up it was an problem in the browser. Reinstalling did the trick.
Thanks for the article, i'll give it a look.